# Comma categories for defining cones

Tags: category-theory, universal-property

[I read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cone_(category_theory)#Category_of_cones), that a comma category $\Delta \downarrow D$ is a category, where the cones are just morphisms. $\Delta$ is the diagonal functor to category of diagrams, $D$ is the diagram.

However, a requirement for a comma category $S \downarrow T$ is that, $S, T$ have a matching codomain, however:

$$
\Delta: \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C}^\mathcal{J} \\
D: \mathcal{J} \to \mathcal{C}
$$

What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here $D$ is not being thought of as a functor $\mathcal{J}\to\mathcal{C}$.  Instead, it is being considered a functor $1\to\mathcal{C}^\mathcal{J}$, where $1$ is the category with one object and one morphism.  Such a functor is of course essentially the same thing as an object of $\mathcal{C}^\mathcal{J}$, so any diagram canonically determines such a functor.

Comment: Is $D(\ast)$ then what previously was $D$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.